# Shorthand for "import or install"?

Tags: python

Is there a shorthand in Python for this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
try:
  import tornado
except ImportError:
  print("Import not found, installing ...")
  import os
  os.system("sudo pip3 install tornado");
  import tornado
```

The idea is for code to "just work, no questions asked" rather than complaining with an ImportError. Also, the code above requires me to write "tornado" 3 times, which isn't very DRY. That is, is there something effectively equivalent to:

```
import_and_dont_complain "tornado"
```

Comment: That isn't going to work on the (many) systems where `sudo` is configured to require a TTY.

Comment: ...also, invoking a shell (as `os.system()` does) is adding unfortunate and unnecessary security vulnerabilities without any benefit over a direct `execv`.

Comment: *something effectively equivalent to:* `import_and_dont_complain` ... you could use the [Python error steamroller](https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy) (somewhat NSFW). Otherwise I don't think Python has any idioms which allow you to automatically download missing modules. Just put the required third-party modules in a `requirements.txt` and run `pip[3] install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: What's the difference between giving a piece of code permissions to run `sudo` at will and running it as root directly? Especially if it's a service that retrieves software from the Internet. Keep in mind that `pip` can be passed arbitrary URLs to download software from, so even if you restrict permissions to only call `sudo pip3`, it's still a huge, glaring vulnerability.

Comment: As a matter of principle I would personally rather a piece of software terminate here with an error stating that I need to install this, that, and the other dependency. If a program I was using tried to do this, I would be upset and might uninstall it.

Answer (score 4):

The proper solution would be to declare the dependency in your `setup.py`.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='herro',
      version='0.1',
      description='Is anybody there?',
      url='http://herro.example.com/',
      author='yourself',
      author_email='you@example.com',
      license='GPL',
      packages=['herro'],
      install_requires=['tornado'],  # <----- here
      zip_safe=False)
```

http://python-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dependencies.html

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. This is very much the right answer, as opposed to the literal answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sudo` here is a very bad idea. Better to use a virtualenv writable directly by the process if you're going to allow it to install its own code, rather than letting it modify the entire system. (That said, letting a network service modify its own code is **also** a major security flaw; thus, you shouldn't be doing this at all, but instead using an installation process that ensures that dependencies are present ahead-of-time).

That said:

---

```
import subprocess

def import_and_dont_complain(name, globaldict=None):
    try:
        module = __import__(name)
    except ImportError:
        subprocess.check_call(['sudo', 'pip3', 'install', name])
        module = __import__(name)
    if globaldict is not None:
        globaldict[name] = module
    return module
```

...used as either:

```
import_and_dont_complain('tornado', globals())
```

...or...

```
tornado = import_and_dont_complain('tornado')
```

---

Passing the `globals` dictionary explicitly lets you call this from modules other than the one it's defined in.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, although you could define your own function to do so, e.g. in a utils.py or some such:

```
from subprocess import call

def import_or_install(package_name):
    try:
        imported = __import__(package_name)
    except ImportError:
        rc = call('sudo pip3 install {0}'.format(package_name).split())
        if rc != 0:
            raise RuntimeError('Could not install required package!')
        imported = __import__(package_name)
    return imported
```

Then from whatever module you're working in:

```
from utils import import_or_install

tornado = import_or_install('tornado')
```

That being said, I'm not sure why you'd want to do this. If you're making a package, just define whatever third party modules you need as dependencies, and pip will install them automatically when a user installs your package.

Also note that the above solution doesn't recursively check for failure. If the pip install fails, you'll still get an `ImportError`.

Another note, see Charles' point below. Especially if you need to specify version strings, manually splitting the call into a list is going to be much more resilient.

Comment: `subprocess.call()` doesn't use `os.system()` either. But yeah, your answer has the advantage of being globally available, although personally I like to avoid globals where possible.

Comment: `globals()` are still module-scoped, same as any other `import` statement at the top of a file would be.

Comment: Consider, for instance, `['pip', 'install', 'software == version']` vs `['pip', 'install', 'software', '==', 'version']` -- the former is more correct, but split() will always do the latter if given `'pip install software == version'` as input. Likewise for passing filenames or URLs with literal spaces.

Comment: You're right regarding the `split()`. It's purely a convenience, and it could cause problems in some cases. It's just easier for quick one-off calls than writing out the list. I made an edit above to address that case. Thanks.

Comment: Is it really? `call(['sudo', 'pip3', 'install', package_name])` is 47 characters; `call('sudo pip3 install {0}'.format(package_name).split())` is 58.

Comment: Maybe not, especially with variable insertion, but I'm liable to put a comma inside the ticks, then have to backspace, etc. As such, it's often easier for me to just type the command and split it.